# Distinct Child Threads not Being Created

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Java program in which I am creating a distributed key-value store. For context, I have 2 objects, a Server and a ReplicaPoller, each of which are Runnable. In the Server object I have,

```
public class Server implements Runnable {
    boolean createdPoller = false;
    // ...
    
    public void run() {
        // ...
        if (!createdPoller) {
            ReplicaPoller replicaPoller = new ReplicaPoller();
            Thread replicaPollerThread = new Thread(replicaPoller);
            replicaPollerThread.start();
            createdPoller = true;
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

And in ReplicaPoller I have,

```
public class ReplicaPoller implements Runnable {
    // ...

    public void run() {
        logger.info(hostServer.name + " " + Thread.currentThread().threadId());
());
        // hostServer is the server that created this instance of Replica Poller.
        // ...
    }
}
```

However when I create 2 Server objects, their corresponding ReplicaPoller's log the same thread ID. Any intracasy I seem to be missing? I'm creating new instances of the ReplicaPollers' threads in the Server object, so I'm not sure why they're using the same thread.

**Edit:** For additional context, I have an external configuration service that will create the servers by executing, `Runtime.getRunTime().exec("java -jar server.jar -p port -n name")`. Where `-p` parameter is the port the server listens on and `-n` is a unique identifier for the server (serverAddress:port). Furthermore, I'm using log4j for logging purposes, in which all created servers and ReplicaPollers share the same root logger and log to a file: server.log. It is in this file where I am seeing the same thread log the following:

```
2023-03-21 13:21:33,447 INFO  [Thread-2] 127.0.0.1:8029: 127.0.0.1:8029 25
```

AND

```
2023-03-21 13:21:37,648 INFO  [Thread-2] 127.0.0.1:8062: 127.0.0.1:8062 25
```

FYI I'm not sure why some are saying they are getting compiler errors with the `threadId()` method call because it works for me, and the reason why I don't use `getId()` is because my IDE (Idea) said it was deprecated ... (Using Java JDK 19).

Comment: interesting, there is no `ThreadID()` method in java tho. Im assuming you are creating two server objects by just doing `new Server()`?

Comment: As JSelser pointed out, the code in the question doesn't compile. It's also missing the code that creates the `Server` objects. I tried to reproduce by changing `ThreadID` to `getId`, and added a `main` method to `Server` that creates two instances and runs them. That produced two different thread IDs. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question with a working reproduction.

Comment: Hey thanks for the helpful comments, I updated the question with more context that should hopefully make things more clear.